# Android DNS MX record lookup

Tags: java, android, dns, lookup, mx-record

I want to lookup dns mx records an the android platform.
When using http://www.dnsjava.org on android  `new Lookup("gmail.com", Type.MX).run();` always returns null.

```
    import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
    import org.xbill.DNS.MXRecord;
    import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
    import org.xbill.DNS.TextParseException;
    import org.xbill.DNS.Type;


List<String> targets = new ArrayList<String>();
Record[] records;  

    records = new Lookup("gmail.com", Type.MX).run();

    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
     MXRecord mx = (MXRecord) records[i];
     targets.add("Host " + mx.getTarget() + " has preference  "+ mx.getPriority());
    }
```

Any ideas or alternatives?
Thanks!

Comment: which version of dnsjava are you using?  I've successfully used dnsjava 1.6.6 on Android before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally forgot to set the permission and unfortunately no exception has been thrown...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```